# How to retrieve JSON element from feed when jQuery $.parseJSON doesn't like YouTube JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string, youtube

With array notation such as the following:

```
$.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) 
{
    var id = item['id']['$t'];
});
```

I can retrieve the `id` field from a Youtube JSON feed as this string:

```
tag:youtube.com,2008:video:W5XpXU8TBoo
```

corresponding to this JSON:

```
entry: [

    *
      -
      {
          o
            -
            id: {
                + $t: "tag:youtube.com,2008:video:W5XpXU8TBoo"
            }
```

When I try to use `$.parseJSON` to retrieve the `video` value, it says this is not valid JSON:

```
$.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) 
{
    var id = item['id']['$t'];
            var video = $.parseJSON(item['id']['$t']).video;
});
```

**Is there another way to get the video value (i.e.: `W5XpXU8TBoo`) from this JSON element?**

Comment: What does your call to youtube look like?  If it's called correctly, it's valid JSON.  You've abbreviated the code much too much here.

Comment: Sorry. This is the Youtube URL: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=roberto+carlos&max-results=10&v=2&alt=json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the video ID elsewhere in the returned object a bit simpler, like this:

```
$.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
  var id = this.media$group.yt$videoid.$t;
  //use id
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/L35Vs/).